# Initial tab doesn't fire open, ready events

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, firefox-addon-restartless

I'm build an SDK Firefox Add-on that is supposed to read a tab's URL and parse it. To this end, I'm listening to the `'ready'` event in `lib/main.js`,

```
var tabs = require('sdk/tabs');
tabs.on('open', function(tab){
  tab.on('ready', function(tab){
    console.log(tab.url);
  });
});
```

as described in [Mozilla's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/tabs).

When debugging with `cfx run`, this appears to work well for new tabs. The tab that's already open on `cfx run`, however does *not* fire the `open` and `ready` events.

What's the reason for this and how to fix it?

Comment: I think you made a sdk addon. sdk uses bootstrap but is not really classified as bootstrap addon :P

Comment: @Noitidart You're right, this is with the SDK. Anything you can suggest to fix this?

Comment: I'm not sure i'm bootstrap guy not sdk :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To list all tabs that were open at the moment of loading the addon you could just use the `tabs` object you got after requiring `sdk/tabs`

```
var tabs = require('sdk/tabs');
for (var tab of tabs) {
  console.log(tab.url);
}
```

So the code from your example could be transformed to something like this:

```
var tabs = require('sdk/tabs');

for (let tab of tabs) {
  processTab(tab);
}

tabs.on('open', function(tab){
  tab.on('ready', processTab);
});

function processTab(tab) {
  console.log(tab.url);
}
```